# How to pass multiple variable from PHP to extenal js file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I can't pass multiple variable from PHP (after fectch data from mysql) to js extenal file. So if I use `echo $x_1` it can pass to `#watts_value` in html file and display normally. 
But I want to pass variable `$x_1` to `#watts_value` and `$x_2` to `kwh_value`. I already try to do that but it just pass all value to the `#watts_value`. 
I have no idea about how to pass variable from php to javascript. Please suggest me or tell me how to do this.

**This is my html**

```
<div id="watts_value"></div>
<div id="kwh_value"></div>
```

**This is my main.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
 function read(){
  $.post("get_db.php", 
  function(data, status){
 
  if(status == 'success'){
   $('#watts_value').html(data);
  }
  else{
   $('#info').html("Error!");
  }
  });
 };
 read();
 setInterval(read,1000);
    });
```

**This is my php file**

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="rt_db";
$tbname="rt_data";

$conn=new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}


$sql_1="SELECT * FROM $tbname WHERE SensorId ='1'";
$sql_2="SELECT * FROM $tbname WHERE SensorId ='2'";

$result_1=$conn->query($sql_1);
$result_2=$conn->query($sql_2);

if($result_1->num_rows>0){
    while($row=$result_1->fetch_assoc()){
        $x_1=$row['SensorData'];
        echo $x_1;
    }
}
if($result_2->num_rows>0){
    while($row=$result_2->fetch_assoc()){
        $x_2=$row['SensorData'];
        echo $x_2;
    }
}

else {
    echo "fail";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You should look up the `IN` clause, as in `WHERE SensorId IN (1,2)` instead of running two separate queries.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing `@` operator obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to create a JSON response to grab the different 'variables':

```
$jsonObject = ['WattsValue' => [], 'KwhValue' => []];

while($row = $result_1->fetch_assoc()){
    $jsonObject['WattsValue'][] = $row['SensorData'];
}

while($row = $result_2->fetch_assoc()){
    $jsonObject['KwhValue'][] = $row['SensorData'];
}

$conn->close();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($jsonObject);
http_response_code(200);
exit;
```

When using jQuery, it'll recognize this as being JSON and giving the ability to use the JSON object directly:

```
$.post("get_db.php", 
    function(data, status){

    if(status === 'success'){
        $('#watts_value').text(data.WattsValue.join(','));
        $('#kwh_value').text(data.KwhValue.join(','));
    }
});
```

Comment: This work for my case, you saved my day. Thank you so much.  :)

Comment: I confused that how to use these 2 variables `$jsonObject['WattsValue'][]` and `$jsonObject['KwhValue'][]` in highchart. I placed that 2 vars in my highchart but it can't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in PHP to output a JSON string of an array. Then you can output the result on client side to see the response. It should be a javascript object.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. It is my new lesson. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can put the values you need to pass through a request to an array, json encode it and echo it.

you may find the following thread useful.

[Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

The result of your request returns both `@$x_1` and `@$x_2` as one string. You can return JSON object with keys for x_1 and x_2

Comment: Yes, JSON is the answer, thank you for your help. :)
I will remember that if different variable want to passes, we must use JSON.